# How can I make the Android browser render my document at the screen's size?

Tags: android, mobile-safari, android-browser

I'm working on a site that's supposed to scale fluently down to low resolutions, so that it would work just as well on a phone.  This works well in Firefox and Chrome when I just make the window small, but when I try it out on an actual Android phone (Nexus One running Android 2.2), it renders it super-huge!  (Using JS's window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight properties, it seems the viewport resolution it reports is 800x1271!)

Is there a way to render the page at actual-size in the browser window so I can have my full design show up on the phone?  User-agent sniffing is allowed, JS is allowed but discouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved on my own.  The solution is to add the following code to the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width">
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for answering your own problem – you got me to my solution, too.

Just some extra info for anyone else with a similar problem, I got the following results using jQuery `$(window).width()` / `$(window).height()` on a Nexus One running Android 2.2.

No `<meta name="viewport">`

– portrait 800 x 1130, landscape 800 x 358

With `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

– portrait 320 x 452, landscape 533 x 239

With `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">`

– portrait 480 x 678, landscape 800 x 358 – the real pixel dimensions!

I've not been able to test it on an iPhone: if anyone wants to try, the test is [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/dev/window-size.html).

Comment: Hmmm, still not quite what I was looking for – the reported window dimensions now change as I zoom. Could be effective, but not what I was expecting...